# SQL Downselect query results based on field duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I'm looking for a little help with a SQL query. (I am using Oracle.)

I have a query that is a union of 2 differing select statments.  The resulting data looks like the following:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3
XXX      ValA     Val1
XXX      ValB     Val2
YYY      ValA     Val1
YYY      ValA     Val2
```

In this setup the Col1 = XXX are default values and Col1 = YYY are real values.  Real values (YYY) should take precidence over default values.  The actual values are defined via columns 2 and 3.

I'm looking to downselect those results into the following:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3
XXX      ValB     Val2
YYY      ValA     Val1
YYY      ValA     Val2
```

Notice that the first row was removed ... that's because there is a real value (YYY in row 3) took precidence over the default value (XXX).

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: It's not at all clear what makes YYY a "real value" and XXX a "default value". Without some way to distinguish which is preferred, you're going to have a hard time accomplishing this.

Comment: YYY is just a place holder for a real name that I know via another query.  XXX is a set string value for default values.  I already have that problem solved.  thanks.

Comment: is there only one YYY value for each Col2, Col3 pair, or there could be more than one?

Comment: There would be only 1 YYY value (maybe none in which case the XXX value would be used)

Comment: @typhoid: You missed the point of my comment. This problem can't be solved if we don't know that XXX is a constant, which isn't stated in your scenario. Knowing that it is a constant lets us test for it directly (which you'll notice that all of the answers do).

Answer (score 2):

You want to filter out all the rows where col2 and col3 appear with XXX and with another value.

You can implement this filter by doing appropriate counts in a subquery using the analytic functions:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by col2, col3) as numcombos,
             sum(case when col1 = 'XXX' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col2, col3) as numxs
      from t
     ) t
where numcombos = numxs or (col1 <> 'xxx')
```

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is to use an analytic function:

```
select distinct 
       first_value(col1) 
          over (partition by col2, col3 
                order by case col1 
                when 'XXX' then 1 
                else 0 end asc) as col1,
       col2, 
       col3 
from table1
```

However, if the table is large and indexed, it might be better to solve this with a full outer join (which is possible because there are only two possible values):

```
select coalesce(rl.col1, dflt.col1) as col1, 
       coalesce(rl.col2, dflt.col2) as col2,
       coalesce(rl.col3, dflt.col3) as col3
from (select * from table1 where col1 = 'XXX') dflt
full outer join (select * from table1 where col1 <> 'XXX') rl
on dflt.col2 = rl.col2 and dflt.col3 = rl.col3;
```

[[Solution in SQLFiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e502/7)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a trick like this:

```
select
  case when
  max(case when col1<>'XXX' then col1 end) is null then 'XXX' else
  max(case when col1<>'XXX' then col1 end) end as col1, 
  col2,
  col3
from
  your_table
group by col2, col3
```

I transform default value to null, then i group by col3. The maximum value between null and a value is the value you are looking for. This works on your example data, but it might not be exactly what you are looking for, it depends on how your real data is.